# Cohql - apply filter for value which is inside map or list

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, oracle-coherence

I am using cohql for querying cache. I have one cached object which has a Hashmap as a property. Now when get a cache using `get(key)` and get `NamedCache` object.

I want to apply filter based on some value of property which is present inside the map. 
I have used like this -

```
QueryHelper.createFilter(“Obj.map{‘propertyName’}= ‘xyz’ “)

QuertHelper.createFilter(“Obj.list[‘property’]”)
```

But not working.

Anybody has any idea ?

Or how we query for collection data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on complex data types in coherence cache is similar to as we work normally with Java APIs

For query map like object in cohql we can use 
For map -

```
QueryHelper.createQuery(“Obj.get(‘key’) = ‘xyz’”)
```

For detailed info - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22622/strings.htm#BEIDEFED